# python os.walk to save everything in a directory

Tags: python

This script saves the files as `"/home/name/main/all my files and stuff"`. I want to save it as `"main/all my files and stuff"`.

```
def zipit ():
  file_paths = ['/home/name/main/']
  buffer= StringIO.StringIO()
  z= zipfile.ZipFile( buffer, "w" )
  for p in file_paths:
    for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(p):
      for f in files:
        z.write(os.path.join(dir, f))
  z.close()
  buffer.seek(0)
  final = HttpResponse(buffer.read())
  final['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=dbs_custom_library.zip'
  final['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-zip'
  return final
```

Comment: it works, but it saves starting from "/home" i want it save starting at "/main"

Comment: Where in this script do you specify that you want to walk from '/main/' instead of '/home/'?

Comment: Im nnot sure I even know how to specify to start walking from "/main" how would I do this?

Comment: @JoelCornett You do not understand the problem. He **is** walking from `main` but the folder structure in the zip file is wrong (it is starting with `/home`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `zipfile` stores the complete path you are giving to `ZipFile.write`. But you can modify the path in the zip with the `arcname` parameter ([ref](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)).

So you need just to strip off `'/home/name/'` from the filename:

```
filename = os.path.join(dir, f)
z.write(filename, arcname=filename[11:])
```